# If eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ is let's say, $1$ and $-2$, then…

Tags: matrices

What would be the eigenvalues of $A^2-3A+1$? Also what will the eigenvectors of the polynomial equation, will they be same as that of matrix $A$?

Comment: Let's say the eigenvectors of A is x1 and x2, what would they be in terms of x1 and x2?

Comment: Apply that matrix equation to each of $x_1$ and $x_2$. What do you get?

Comment: I got the eigenvalues values of the said equation by putting the eigen values of A, but what about eigen vectors of the equation ?